# Vim key mapping compile and run for Java and C code

Tags: java, vim, compilation, mapping

Here's what the lines in my .vimrc look like:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(%)<cr>
autocmd FileType java nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!javac' shellescape(%) && '!java' shellescape(%:r)<cr>
autocmd FileType c,cpp nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!gcc' shellescape(%) && './a.out'<cr>
```

The Python map executes fine.
The Java map will compile alright, but won't run. I'm not entirely sure if my syntax is correct.
I don't know what's going on with the C version of the map...it keeps displayig the message:

```
"error: Class names, 'test.C,test', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested"
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the syntax is slightly wrong (for all of them!). If you intend to issue two `:!` calls, these must be separated by `|` (escaped `<Bar>` in a mapping), not `&&`:

```
autocmd FileType java nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!javac' shellescape(%) <Bar> exec '!java' shellescape(%:r)<cr>
```

But better do this with a single call: The `&&` must then be quoted, so that it is evaluated by the shell launched by `:!`, not Vim:

```
autocmd FileType java nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!javac' shellescape(%) '&& java' shellescape(%:r)<cr>
```

Furthermore, the special `%` keyword is only recognized directly in the command-line, not when using it in an `:execute` expression. You need to wrap this with `expand()`. Oh, and `shellescape()` should receive an additional flag for proper `:!` escaping.

```
autocmd FileType java nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!javac' shellescape(expand('%'), 1) '&& java' shellescape(expand('%:r'), 1)<cr>
```

Comment: Ah, beautiful! Thanks for the detailed answer, I really appreciate it. Not only does everything execute perfectly now, I understand why also.